# VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I am using ubuntu16.04 and trying to run opencv script.
when i use:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
```

it gives me error VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device
No video window opens
But when i run

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('test.jpg')
```

It opens window shows the picture and close the window.
Please tell me why it is not streaming video directly from camera.

Comment: have you tried with cv2.VideoCapture(0)?

Comment: @api55 0 - is for default PC webcam. it doesn't work.

Comment: @TARS Yes,  I know  what it is for, and that is the reason i asked If OP tried that, since it is not in the question. And my other suggestion is to try to use another backend...

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion api55 gave in his comment

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

is what I would try first.

Generally, you can list the available cameras with `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.  Here sample output:

```
NZXT-U:rt-trx> v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM): (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video1

Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM): (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3):
    /dev/video0
```

`/dev/video0` corresponds to device id 0, etc.

PS: `v4l2-ctl` is quite useful for solving camera issues and can do much more than `--list-devices`.  I installed it via package`v4l-utils` on a 16.04 machine.

Comment: Thank you very much Ulrich for your answer. I did sudo apt-get install cheese and it started working.

Comment: @NeerajSharma, I took a quick look at the OpenCV source code, and `VideoCapture` does support negative device numbers (at least for cap_v4l.cpp), even though this is not in the docs!  You could answer your own question.  If you are not interested, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes i tried with -1 and it worked. Thanks for your support Ulrich.

Answer (score -1):

Late, but to get mine working i put in terminal:

`-ltrh /dev/video*`

To get a list of the video devices that are plugged into my computer. Then for each one I did:

`sudo chmod 777 /dev/videox`

Where x was one of the video files that were listed, giving everything access to them.  Probaly not the most secure solution, but it got my code working.